Upgrade to webpack5 but I have to disable cache to update typescript after a hot reloading
I upgraded the webpack in an Angular project to webpack5. The configuration appears to be correct, and the project starts without issues. However, when I modify a TypeScript file and the application reloads, the changes are not reflected in the reloaded application.
In contrast, when I update a template, the changes are loaded correctly.
If I disable the webpack5 cache, the TypeScript files are updated properly upon reloading the application.
Is there a webpack5 configuration that allows using the cache while still correctly updating TypeScript files?
The project use angular 11 and the package.json devDependencies are
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1102.19",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^11.2.19",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "^1.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "^1.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^1.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.2.14",
    "@babel/core": "^7.25.2",
    "@babel/helper-string-parser": "~7.24.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "~7.25.3",
    ....
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^11.2.19",
    ...
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    ...
    "babel-loader": "~9.1.3",
    ...
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "6.0.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "6.1.1",
    ...
    "ejs-webpack-loader": "^2.2.2",
    ...
    "helmet": "^4.1.0",
    "html-loader": "5.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "5.6.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "1.0.5",
    ...
    "less": "^3.5.0",
    "less-loader": "12.2.0",
    "lint-staged": "^13.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "2.9.0",
    "morgan": "1.10.0",
    "ng-annotate-loader": "0.7.0",
    ...
    "postcss": "~8.4.41",
    "postcss-less": "^6.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "~8.1.1",
    ...
    "sass": "1.32.6",
    "sass-loader": "10.1.1",
    "style-loader": "2.0.0",
    ...
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "~5.3.10",
    "ts-loader": "~9.5.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "~4.1.6",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.94.0",
    "webpack-cli": "~5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "~7.4.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~5.0.4",
    "webpack-merge": "~6.0.1",
    "webpack-split-by-path": "~2.0.0",
    "webpack-stream": "~7.0.0",
    ...
},

Webpack configuration has two files
webpack.js
"use strict";

var path = require("path"),
    webpack = require("webpack"),
    HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin"),
    CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require("fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

const AngularWebpackPlugin = require("@ngtools/webpack").AngularCompilerPlugin;

const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

...

var pathSep = path.sep === "\\" ? "\\\\" : path.sep;
var fontRegex = new RegExp(
    "fonts" +
        pathSep +
        "[^" +
        pathSep +
        "]*\\.(woff(2)?|png|jpg|jpeg|ttf|eot|svg)(\\?v=[0-9]\\.[0-9]\\.[0-9])?$"
);
var imageRegex = new RegExp(
    "img" +
        pathSep +
        "([^\\.]+)\\.(woff(2)?|png|jpg|jpeg|ttf|eot|svg)(\\?v=[0-9]\\.[0-9]\\.[0-9])?$"
);

var config = {
    cache: true,
    entry: {
        brapp: path.resolve(APP_DIR, "src/main.ts"),
        ...
    },

    output: {
        clean:  true,
        path: ...
        filename: "assets/bundle/[name].[fullhash].js",
        publicPath: "/",
        library: ["brapp", "[name]"],
        libraryTarget: "umd",
        devtoolNamespace: "brapp"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                loader: "html-loader",
                options: {
                    sources: false
                },
                test: /\.html$/i
            },
            // this rule matches images and fonts under the fonts directory and copies them under assets/fonts
            {
                test: fontRegex,
                loader: "file-loader",
                options: {
                    name: "fonts/[name].[ext]",
                    outputPath: "assets/",
                    transpileOnly: true
                }
            },
            // this rule matches images and fonts under the img directory and copies them under assets/img
            {
                test: imageRegex,
                loader: "file-loader",
                options: {
                    name: "img/[1].[ext]",
                    outputPath: "assets/",
                    regExp: imageRegex
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "@ngtools/webpack"
            },
            {
                test: /\.[cm]js$/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        cacheDirectory: true,
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
                    },
                    "css-loader",
                    "sass-loader"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },

    resolve: {
        ...
    },

    optimization: {
        concatenateModules: true, // ModuleConcatenationPlugin
        emitOnErrors: false,
        minimize: true,
        moduleIds: "named", // NamedModulesPlugin()
        splitChunks: {
            // CommonsChunkPlugin()
            cacheGroups: {
                commons: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: "vendor",
                    chunks: function (chunk) {
                        return chunk.name !== "corejs";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },

    plugins: [
        new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
            async: true
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            _: "lodash",
            moment: "moment",
            momentTimezone: "moment-timezone"
        }),
        ...
        new CopyWebpackPlugin({
            patterns: [
                {
                    from: "src/assets",
                    to: "assets/",
                    globOptions: {
                        ignore: ["**/less/**"],
                        copyUnmodified: true
                    }
                }
            ]
        }),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        ...
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
        new AngularWebpackPlugin({
            emitClassMetadata: true,
            forkTypeChecker: true,
            skipCodeGeneration: true,
            tsConfigPath: "./tsconfig.json"
        })
    ],
    profile: true,
    stats: {
        hash: true,
        version: true,
        timings: true,
        assets: true,
        chunks: true,
        modules: true,
        reasons: true,
        children: true,
        source: false,
        errors: true,
        errorDetails: true,
        warnings: true,
        publicPath: true
    }
};

module.exports = config;

webpack.dev.js
"use strict";

const Webpack = require("webpack");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        hot: true
    },
    devtool: "eval-cheap-source-map",
    mode: "development",
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        options: {
                            publicPath: "/"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "postcss-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "less-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
                        cacheDirectory: true
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        ...
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "assets/css/[name].css"
        })
    ]
};

